# Visual Studio a way to show operators as opposed to text Example: ≠ instead of !=

Tags: c#, unicode, visual-studio-2017

I had to reinstall everything on my computer including Visual Studio, my question is, before I reinstalled Visual Studio was showing the code on my C# programs in a method using Unicode operators for example:

```
if (1 ≠ 2) {
}
```

instead of

```
if (1 != 2) {
}
```

However upon reinstalling Visual Studio they've reverted back to the text format, does anyone know what setting I need to enable to get them to show as the Unicode versions?

Any help you could give would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want to see fake code?  o . O

Comment: Because I liked the cleaner look it gave me.

Comment: I never asked for a link?

Comment: This was a custom font; VS does not support this natively.

Comment: You need a font.  You don't have a font. How do you get a font?

Comment: Don't do that! Please. Think about your future self trying to compile that elsewhere

Comment: @RegisPortalez, there's no problem compiling or even viewing it elsewhere. The file still contains a "!=", the font just contains a hint to *display* those two characters next to each other as "≠".

Comment: Great question. While I won't be using this font, I don't see a reason to complain about its use. I'm also not entirely sure how this would make it difficult for your future self. Ignore these comments and use whatever font you're comfortable with.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just need to install a font that includes programming ligatures, and then to tell VS to use that font. I believe [Fira Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) is currently the most complete programming font.

Comment: Definitely a plus to see an answer instead of the other comments. I don't see myself using this font but that doesn't change how answering a question like this doesn't require an opinion of whether the goal is useful or not.